# Bootstrap: Calendar not working in their website?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/examples/dashboard/

I clicked the "This Week" button but the calendar does not show up anymore. I tried on another computer and I get the same result. Is there a new update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap does not provide a calendar popup. Furthermore, if you look in the inspector, no listener listens for events on this button so it is normal that nothing pops up when you click on it:

[image: Screenshot of the inspector]

If you are looking for a javascript calendar library for your website you can find many on google. I have used this one on many projects, works like a charm: https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/.